# Dynamic import programmatically

Tags: java, dynamic, import, package, classloader

I simply want to implement that line programmatically in runtime.

> import com.company.package.*;

I can't believe all the searches lead to Python, and I certainly would prefer not loading classes and looping one by one. It must be a faster command.

Any suggestion?

P.S: I know it's not the best of designs, but I am doing it through a JSP, so perhaps there is some way to use a parameter in the declaration as in

`<%@ page import=%{myPackage} %>`

Comment: what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: look on Class.forName("com.company.package.ClassName")

Comment: I am trying to force my JSP import a package by means of a given parameter. I know it's not a best practice kind of thing, but let's say I want to do it that way. Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: Class.forName only loads a class at a given time as far as I know, I prefer not to loop/retrieve all classes and load them. I am seeking a way to translate that simple line for whole package import package.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassLoader is too dynamic/flexible to do what you're asking.  Specifically, there is no portable way to list the contents of a directory from a ClassLoader, so there is no way to determine the complete set of classes to be loaded.  Here are two *non-portable* suggestions:

1. *Assume* your ClassLoader implements URLClassLoader, then call getURLs, then *assume* the URLs are `file:` ...or:
2. *Assume* ClassLoader.getResource("com/company/package/") will return a non-null URL, then *assume* the URL will be `file:` (or `jar:`, then *assume* the inner URL is `file:`, and then extract and use that)

In either case, parse `file:` URL (handling URL decoding), list the contents of the directory/JAR to find all `*.class` files.

Note, this is basically what Spring `classpath*:` does, and they include several portability warnings in their [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-ctx-wildcards-in-resource-paths) for these reasons.